# Tomcat7 start at server startup

Tags: server, startup, tomcat7

My ubuntu 13.10 was configured to start apache2 and tomcat7 at startup, but (maybe for automatic system updates) they don't auto-start at startup anymore.

I've solved apache2 auto start with the following commands:

```
update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
update-rc.d apache2 add
update-rc.d apache2 enable
```

But same ones for tomcat7 did not work!
I searched at logs looking for errors but nothing found.

THIS WORKS:

```
service tomcat7 start
```

my /etc/init.d/tomcat7 standard file:

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #
    # /etc/init.d/tomcat7 -- startup script for the Tomcat 6 servlet engine
    #
    # Written by Miquel van Smoorenburg <miquels@cistron.nl>.
    # Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>.
    # Modified for Tomcat by Stefan Gybas <sgybas@debian.org>.
    # Modified for Tomcat6 by Thierry Carrez <thierry.carrez@ubuntu.com>.
    # Modified for Tomcat7 by Ernesto Hernandez-Novich <emhn@itverx.com.ve>.
    # Additional improvements by Jason Brittain <jason.brittain@mulesoft.com>.
    #
    ### BEGIN INIT INFO
    # Provides:          tomcat7
    # Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network
    # Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network
    # Should-Start:      $named
    # Should-Stop:       $named
    # Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop:      0 1 6
    # Short-Description: Start Tomcat.
    # Description:       Start the Tomcat servlet engine.
    ### END INIT INFO

    set -e


echo "============================================================================" >> /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
echo "$(date) /etc/init.d/tomcat -> starting/stoping/restarting" >> /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
echo "============================================================================" >> /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out


    PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
    NAME=tomcat7
    DESC="Tomcat servlet engine"
    DEFAULT=/etc/default/$NAME
    JVM_TMP=/tmp/tomcat7-$NAME-tmp

    if [ `id -u` -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "You need root privileges to run this script"
            exit 1
    fi

    # Make sure tomcat is started with system locale
    if [ -r /etc/default/locale ]; then
            . /etc/default/locale
            export LANG
    fi

    . /lib/lsb/init-functions

    if [ -r /etc/default/rcS ]; then
            . /etc/default/rcS
    fi


    # The following variables can be overwritten in $DEFAULT

    # Run Tomcat 7 as this user ID and group ID
    TOMCAT7_USER=tomcat7
    TOMCAT7_GROUP=tomcat7
    # this is a work-around until there is a suitable runtime replacement
    # for dpkg-architecture for arch:all packages
    # this function sets the variable OPENJDKS
    find_openjdks()
    {
            for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-*
            do
                    if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-common" ]
                    then
                            OPENJDKS=$jvmdir
                    fi
            done
            for jvmdir in /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-*
            do
                    if [ -d "${jvmdir}" -a "${jvmdir}" != "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-common" ]
                    then
                            OPENJDKS="${OPENJDKS} ${jvmdir}"
                    fi
            done
    }

    OPENJDKS=""
    find_openjdks
    # The first existing directory is used for JAVA_HOME (if JAVA_HOME is not
    # defined in $DEFAULT)
    JDK_DIRS="/usr/lib/jvm/default-java ${OPENJDKS} /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle"

    # Look for the right JVM to use
    for jdir in $JDK_DIRS; do
        if [ -r "$jdir/bin/java" -a -z "${JAVA_HOME}" ]; then
            JAVA_HOME="$jdir"
        fi
    done
    export JAVA_HOME

    # Directory where the Tomcat 6 binary distribution resides
    CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME

    # Directory for per-instance configuration files and webapps
    CATALINA_BASE=/var/lib/$NAME
    # Use the Java security manager? (yes/no)
    TOMCAT7_SECURITY=no

    # Default Java options
    # Set java.awt.headless=true if JAVA_OPTS is not set so the
    # Xalan XSL transformer can work without X11 display on JDK 1.4+
    # It also looks like the default heap size of 64M is not enough for most cases
    # so the maximum heap size is set to 128M
    if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then
            JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128M"
    fi

    # End of variables that can be overwritten in $DEFAULT
    # overwrite settings from default file
    if [ -f "$DEFAULT" ]; then
            . "$DEFAULT"
    fi

    if [ ! -f "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/bootstrap.jar" ]; then
            log_failure_msg "$NAME is not installed"
            exit 1
    fi

    POLICY_CACHE="$CATALINA_BASE/work/catalina.policy"

    if [ -z "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" ]; then
            CATALINA_TMPDIR="$JVM_TMP"
    fi

    # Set the JSP compiler if set in the tomcat7.default file
    if [ -n "$JSP_COMPILER" ]; then
            JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dbuild.compiler=\"$JSP_COMPILER\""
    fi

    SECURITY=""
    if [ "$TOMCAT7_SECURITY" = "yes" ]; then
            SECURITY="-security"
    fi

    # Define other required variables
    CATALINA_PID="/var/run/$NAME.pid"
    CATALINA_SH="$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh"

    # Look for Java Secure Sockets Extension (JSSE) JARs
    if [ -z "${JSSE_HOME}" -a -r "${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/jsse.jar" ]; then
        JSSE_HOME="${JAVA_HOME}/jre/"
    fi
    catalina_sh() {
            # Escape any double quotes in the value of JAVA_OPTS
            JAVA_OPTS="$(echo $JAVA_OPTS | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g')"

            AUTHBIND_COMMAND=""
            if [ "$AUTHBIND" = "yes" -a "$1" = "start" ]; then
                    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
                    AUTHBIND_COMMAND="/usr/bin/authbind --deep /bin/bash -c "
            fi

            # Define the command to run Tomcat's catalina.sh as a daemon
            # set -a tells sh to export assigned variables to spawned shells.
            TOMCAT_SH="set -a; JAVA_HOME=\"$JAVA_HOME\"; source \"$DEFAULT\"; \
                    CATALINA_HOME=\"$CATALINA_HOME\"; \
                    CATALINA_BASE=\"$CATALINA_BASE\"; \
                    JAVA_OPTS=\"$JAVA_OPTS\"; \
                    CATALINA_PID=\"$CATALINA_PID\"; \
                    CATALINA_TMPDIR=\"$CATALINA_TMPDIR\"; \
                    LANG=\"$LANG\"; JSSE_HOME=\"$JSSE_HOME\"; \
                    cd \"$CATALINA_BASE\"; \
                    \"$CATALINA_SH\" $@"

            if [ "$AUTHBIND" = "yes" -a "$1" = "start" ]; then
                    TOMCAT_SH="'$TOMCAT_SH'"
            fi

            # Run the catalina.sh script as a daemon
            set +e
            touch "$CATALINA_PID" "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
            chown $TOMCAT7_USER "$CATALINA_PID" "$CATALINA_BASE"/logs/catalina.out
            start-stop-daemon --start -b -u "$TOMCAT7_USER" -g "$TOMCAT7_GROUP" \
                    -c "$TOMCAT7_USER" -d "$CATALINA_TMPDIR" -p "$CATALINA_PID" \
                    -x /bin/bash -- -c "$AUTHBIND_COMMAND $TOMCAT_SH"
            status="$?"
            set +a -e
            return $status
    }

    case "$1" in
      start)
            if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
                    log_failure_msg "no JDK or JRE found - please set JAVA_HOME"
                    exit 1
            fi

            if [ ! -d "$CATALINA_BASE/conf" ]; then
                    log_failure_msg "invalid CATALINA_BASE: $CATALINA_BASE"
                    exit 1
            fi

            log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
            if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                    --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                    >/dev/null; then

                    # Regenerate POLICY_CACHE file
                    umask 022
                    echo "// AUTO-GENERATED FILE from /etc/tomcat7/policy.d/" \
                            > "$POLICY_CACHE"
                    echo ""  >> "$POLICY_CACHE"
                    cat $CATALINA_BASE/conf/policy.d/*.policy \
                            >> "$POLICY_CACHE"

                    # Remove / recreate JVM_TMP directory
                    rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
                    mkdir -p "$JVM_TMP" || {
                            log_failure_msg "could not create JVM temporary directory"
                            exit 1
                    }
                    chown $TOMCAT7_USER "$JVM_TMP"

                    catalina_sh start $SECURITY
                    sleep 5
                    if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                            --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                            >/dev/null; then
                            if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                                    rm -f "$CATALINA_PID"
                            fi
                            log_end_msg 1
                    else
                            log_end_msg 0
                    fi
            else
                    log_progress_msg "(already running)"
                    log_end_msg 0
            fi
            ;;
      stop)
            log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"

            set +e
            if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                    start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                            --user "$TOMCAT7_USER" \
                            --retry=TERM/20/KILL/5 >/dev/null
                    if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
                            log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
                    elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
                            PID="`cat $CATALINA_PID`"
                            log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $NAME (pid $PID)"
                            exit 1
                    fi
                    rm -f "$CATALINA_PID"
                    rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
            else
                    log_progress_msg "(not running)"
            fi
            log_end_msg 0
            set -e
            ;;
       status)
            set +e
            start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                    --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                    >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then

                    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                        log_success_msg "$DESC is not running, but pid file exists."
                            exit 1
                    else
                        log_success_msg "$DESC is not running."
                            exit 3
                    fi
            else
                            log_progress_msg "$DESC is not running but pid file exists, cleaning up"
                    elif [ $? -eq 3 ]; then
                            PID="`cat $CATALINA_PID`"
                            log_failure_msg "Failed to stop $NAME (pid $PID)"
                            exit 1
                    fi
                    rm -f "$CATALINA_PID"
                    rm -rf "$JVM_TMP"
            else
                    log_progress_msg "(not running)"
            fi
            log_end_msg 0
            set -e
            ;;
       status)
            set +e
            start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                    --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                    >/dev/null 2>&1
            if [ "$?" = "0" ]; then

                    if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                        log_success_msg "$DESC is not running, but pid file exists."
                            exit 1
                    else
                        log_success_msg "$DESC is not running."
                            exit 3
                    fi
            else
                    log_success_msg "$DESC is running with pid `cat $CATALINA_PID`"
            fi
            set -e
            ;;
      restart|force-reload)
            if [ -f "$CATALINA_PID" ]; then
                    $0 stop
                    sleep 1
            fi
            $0 start
            ;;
      try-restart)
            if start-stop-daemon --test --start --pidfile "$CATALINA_PID" \
                    --user $TOMCAT7_USER --exec "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" \
                    >/dev/null; then
                    $0 start
            fi
            ;;
      *)
            log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|try-restart|force-reload|status}"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac

    exit 0
```

Any help would be appreciate,
Thanks

Comment: check this 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/223944/how-to-automatically-restart-tomcat7-on-system-reboots

Comment: my /etc/init.d/tomcat7 is more complex than the one in this url, anyway I've followed the steps described & still not working.  And if I try to start it manually with the script defined in 223944 my tomcat is not working properly

Comment: can you reinstal it ?

Comment: It would be an option but I'd prefer to fix it first if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem:

Another init.d script is blocking for several minutes the init.d/tomcat7 execution.

In my case I can see in my console this error repeated several times when startup:

```
2014 Jul  6 11:42:39 vps56629 NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon MTA-v4: cannot bind: Address already in use
2014 Jul  6 11:42:39 vps56629 daemon MTA-v4: problem creating SMTP socket
2
```

When the error appears in console init.d/tomcat7 script starts execution.

I've disabled sendmail, but it wasn't the real prolem.

**The blocking script is iptables rules running too slow because of server lookup operations, **I've just removed the following line in /etc/init.d/iptables and now is ok:****

```
/sbin/iptables -L
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure that both of tomcat & apache aren't online

1st you have to make a link from /etc/rc5.d :

```
cd /etc/rc5.d
sudo ln -s ../init.d/tomcat S71tomcat
sudo ln -s ../init.d/apache S72apache
```

for the tomcat make a file & name it tomcat in this dir /etc/init.d/

```
sudo touch /etc/init.d/tomcat
gksu 'gedit /etc/init.d/tomcat'
```

past this

```
----------------------------  /etc/init.d/tomcat  ------------------------
#!/bin/bash
#
# tomcat        
#
# chkconfig: 
# description:  Start up the Tomcat servlet engine.

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


RETVAL=$?
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/apps/apache/tomcat/jakarta-tomcat-4.0.4"

case "$1" in
 start)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh ];
          then
        echo $"Starting Tomcat"
            /bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        fi
    ;;
 stop)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
          then
        echo $"Stopping Tomcat"
            /bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
        fi
    ;;
 *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
-----------------------  end of /etc/init.d/tomcat  ----------------------
```

for the apache 
$ sudo touch /etc/init.d/apache
$ gksu 'gedit /etc/init.d/apache'

then past this

```
----------------------------  /etc/init.d/apache  ------------------------
#!/bin/bash
#
# apache        
#
# chkconfig: 
# description:  Start up the Apache web server.

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


RETVAL=$?
APACHE_HOME="/usr/apps/apache/apache"

case "$1" in
 start)
    if [ -f $APACHE_HOME/bin/apachectl ]; then
        echo $"Starting Apache"
        $APACHE_HOME/bin/apachectl start
    fi
    ;;
 stop)
    if [ -f $APACHE_HOME/bin/apachectl ]; then
        echo $"Stopping Apache"
        $APACHE_HOME/bin/apachectl stop
    fi
    ;;
 *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
-----------------------  end of /etc/init.d/apache  ----------------------
```

then reboot

```
$ gksu shutdown -r
```

Comment: thanks 4 your reply, my service is called tomcat7, I've allready a lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jul  5 09:53 S20tomcat7 -> ../init.d/tomcat7* at /etc/rc5.d, why should I change my init.d/tomcat7 for your version when my version is the stardard and I didn't change it?

Comment: your init.d/tomcat script is not valid for my tomcat7, tomcat7 has another version that works well calling, for example, service tomcat stop|start|restart.

Comment: you have to change this CATALINA_HOME=
its just an example

Comment: yes, I have noticed, and did it.  But when I run with this script my tomcat is not running well (misconfigured) neither starting at startup.  Have a look at my /etc/init.d/tomcat7 standard file, this one is the standard that ubuntu installs (https://gist.github.com/baylisscg/942150).  I've also noticed the rc5.d entries, in my case where S20apache2 & S20tomcat7 and I've changed to S21tomcat7 & S22apache, the result is the same at startup: apache starts, tomcat doesn't start

Comment: Try to 're install

Comment: why do we need the softlink? (1st you have to make a link from /etc/rc5.d : )